# Is a homomorphisim one-to-one or onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The definition of a homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $H$, given by Pinter, says that: If $G$ and $H$ are groups, a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a function $f: G \rightarrow H$ such that for any two elements $a,b \in G$, $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. If there exists a homomorphism from $G$ **onto** $H$, we say that $H$ is a homomorphic  image of $G$.

So, I am wondering, is a homomorphism onto, or one-to-one? An explanation would be appreciated. It seems to me, that a homomorphism should be just one-to-one.

Comment: Group homomorphism is does not have to be either one-to-one or onto. You are thinking about group *isomorphisms*

Comment: But, doesn't a homomorphism have to take every $a,b \in G$ to some thing in $H$? Whereas, not everything in $H$ must have a pre-image?

Comment: yes but for any $h \in H$, it does not necessitate a $g$ such that $f(g) = h$

Comment: Wouldn't that make one-to-one then?

Comment: How did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: Think about an homomorphism that is neither injective nor onto, for example the trivial homomorphism. I mean let $G$ and $H$ be groups, define $\phi : G \longrightarrow H$ by $\forall g \in G,  f(g) = 1_{H}$.

Comment: @phatty I think you misunderstand one-to-one.  Your phrasing suggests that you imagine it to mean something like "not onto", or "is a function", neither of which is accurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A homomorphism $f:G\to H$ need be neither 1-1 nor onto. It need merely satisfy the requirement that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. Note that the product $ab$ is the product in the domain $G$, while the product $f(a)f(b)$ is the product in the range $H$. One always has that $f(G)\subset H$.

If it is 1-1, it is called a monomorphism.

If it is onto, it is called an epimorphism. This means $f(G)=H$.

If it is both 1-1 and onto, it is called an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to illustrate the falsity of your claim. One of them requires calculus to understand.

For surjectivity, consider the map $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $\Bbb Z$ is the usual integer group be defined by $\phi(x) = 2x.$ The $x = 3$ for instance, has no suitable preimage element.

For injectivity, consider the group $F$ where it is the additive group of smooth functions on $\Bbb R$. The map $\phi: F \to F$ is a homomorphism (by the additive laws of derivatives) defined by $\phi(f) = f'$ , but if we select $f'(x) = e^x$, then it is not injective because the family $f(x) = e^x + c$ maps to $f'(x) = e^x$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, I knew I done goof somewhere, let me make an edit.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems I deleted my comment by mistake. To recap: the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt$ has derivative $f'(x) = e^{x^2}$, and more generally any continuous function has an antiderivative by a similar argument.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, well no. Continuous functions don't belong in our group. We may only select smooth functions.

Comment: Smooth functions are continuous, hence any smooth function has an antiderivative.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, I didn't read you carefully (probably because I am trying to answer another question), I thought you meant to take nonsmooth continuous functions without antiderivatives. In any case this question is answered.